# Why do I have to tap UIDatePicker twice to set time?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker that I want to set to the string value in a textField.  When I tap a second textField, I want the UIDatePicker to take the value in the first textField and use it as the starting time in the datePicker.

This works correctly, but only when I tap the second textField two times.  The first time I tap it, the text field is selected (turns yellow) and the time is set to 6:00 am *every* time!  When I tap the textField again, the timePicker is set correctly...

This is the result of tapping once:

[image]

This is the result of the second tap:

[image]

**UPDATE:** This is the code implemented for the tap:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];   //  don't display the k/b

if (textField.tag == kStartTimeTag)  {
    textFieldTag = kStartTimeTag;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
else if (textField.tag == kEndTimeTag)  {
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];    
    textFieldTag = kEndTimeTag;

    //  now, set end time equal to start time
    [self.oTimePicker setDate:dateFromString(oStartTime.text, @"HH:mm")];

}

return NO;
```

}

Is there a way to make this work on the first tap?

Comment: What code are you implementing when you tap the first time?

Comment: see UPDATE above (I added the code)

Comment: what does the `dateFromString();` block/function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution for anybody who needs to do what I needed done:

```
    [self.oTimePicker setDate:dateFromString(self.oStartTime.text, @"HH:mm")];
    [self.oTimePicker reloadInputViews];
```

The key is the second line:  -reloadInputViews

Thank you everybody for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, since you don't show what you're doing in the function dateFromString(). The code below worked for me on a single tap:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];   //  don't display the k/b

    if (textField.tag == 1)  {
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 2)  {
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        NSDate *startDate = [self timeFromString:self.oStartTime.text];
        [self.oTimePicker setDate:startDate];
    }
    return NO;
}

-(NSDate *)timeFromString:(NSString *)  timeString {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
    return [formatter dateFromString:timeString];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code makes no difference...still have to tap twice...  are you using an actual UIDatePicker?

Comment: @spokane-dude, yes, it's an actual UIDatePicker.

Comment: OK... I just ran another test... the datePicker is being set with the correct date, but it's not displaying it... here is the results of the NSLog from the first tap (it's offset by -0800, but is correct for the Pacific Time zone):    
oStartTime: 12:00
oTimePicker: 2000-01-01 20:00:00 +0000